# In Mvc6, where is WriteAsync function?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am following examples for creating middleware in Mvc6 and all of the examples use the WriteAsync function.  Something like this:

```
if (HttpContext.Request.Path.Value == "/MyHttpHandler")
{
    HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("This is my HttpHandler ...");
}
```

The error I get is: `HttpResponse` does not contain a definition for `WriteAsync` and no extension method 'WriteAsync' accepting a first argument of type `HttpResponse` could be found.

The project was creating in `VS2017`, Asp.Net 5 Template Web Application.

Project dependency:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final"
```

Where is the WriteAsync function?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add dependency:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="1.1.1" />
```

Then in source code add:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

Comment: I don't know if this used to be the right answer but the correct using directive is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http to verify review this: https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Http/HttpResponseWritingExtensions/index.html#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResponseWritingExtensions

Comment: it must be ```using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;```

Answer (score 2):

one package is missing. please add this package "`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions`" and use the namespace "`using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;`" to get the intellisense in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing a simple Middleware. There you can access and edit the Response as well.

Answer (score 1):

use NuGet package manager command line and run this command

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions -Version 2.2.0
```

and import this namespace

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```